# Checkboxes not working in WiX generated windows installer

Tags: wix, setup-project

I've used WiXEdit in conjunction with Wix to reverse engineer an MSI installation in order to move my main solution up to VS2013 from VS2010.

**The error Im getting is that when the MSI is run, the checkboxes and text box I've placed in a dialog act as if they're disabled.** I need the checkboxes as in my main application they allow the user to select a feature set.

I've generated a [simple solution](http://www.mediafire.com/download/k3jy6mzrg7bh8jj/WindowsFormsApplication12_-_Copy.rar) that demonstrates the same error.
The solution has 2(3) projects, windowsformsapplication12 will always be installed, windowsformsapplication1 will only be installed if conditional CHECKBOX1A=1 (SetupProject2 is the wix project and the wix script is found here as setup1.wxs)

(Wix toolkit is necessary to be installed into visual studio to compile the Wix setup project if necessary, but if somebody with installer expertise checks the script [setup1.wxs](http://www.mediafire.com/view/sg78iwz4wewi4rv/Setup1.wxs) they may see what's wrong with it.)

NB
On attempting to compile the reverse engineered file, I received error message "Error 5 The Control element must have a value for exactly one of the Property or CheckBoxPropertyRef attributes." on lines 491,492,493,494. So I added Property="CHECKBOXA1" (or as appropriate) to the end of the control descriptor xml as can be seen if you unrar the source.
I assume I'm missing adding extra code elsewhere or I assume it would work.

This is the first time I've ever encountered a Wix script and the source code doesn't really resemble Wix tutorial code I've seen so I've not been able to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

**Converting VS2010 setup project to a Wix script**

*Please find instructions for anybody else who'd find it useful*

1) Install WixToolkit and WixEdit

2) Build VS2010 setup project

3) Create new Wix project within the solution.

4) Remove the default product.wxs file from the Wix project

5) Copy the setup MSI file to the root directory of the Wix project

6) Run WixEdit application

7) Open the setup MSI file in WixEdit

(This should generate files and directories)

7) Add directories and files generated by WixEdit to the Wix project

8) Compile Wix Setup Project and fix errors

9) Delete the original msi file from the wix project

**Re Check boxes not working**

"Error 5 The Control element must have a value for exactly one of the Property or CheckBoxPropertyRef attributes"

Go to the error line in the script

```
<Control Id="Checkbox1" Type="CheckBox" X="18" Y="108" Width="348" Height="12" Text="{\VSI_MS_Shell_Dlg13.0_0_0}Install Main Application" TabSkip="no"/>
```

Change it so it reads (or appropriate changes)

```
<Control Id="Checkbox1" Type="CheckBox" X="18" Y="108" Width="348" Height="12" Text="{\VSI_MS_Shell_Dlg13.0_0_0}Install Main Application" TabSkip="no" Property="CHECKBOXA1" CheckBoxValue="1" />
```

**CheckBoxValue="1" was the missing attribute that caused my checkboxes to be disabled**